# Setting date to calendar instance in java

Tags: java, calendar

I am using Calendar function to set my custom date to calendar. I am setting it like below this but it is giving different date.

```
int day = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dOutput.getDwDay()));
int monthday = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dOutput.getDwMonth()));
int monthyearday = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dOutput.getDwYear()));

  System.out.println("day = " + day);
  System.out.println("monthday = " + monthday);
  System.out.println("monthyearday = " + monthyearday);
  System.out.println("After setting Time:  " + calendar.getTime());

  calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, monthday);
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, monthyearday);

  int frommonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  System.out.println("year = " + year);
  System.out.println("frommonth = " + frommonth);
```

**OUTPUT**
I am giving this

```
day = 23
monthday = 5
monthyearday = 2014
```

But it is generating like this:

```
year = 2019
frommonth = 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the wrong fields on your calendar. Set the fields like this:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day); // day
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthday); // month
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, monthyearday); // year
```